# Mongoose populate returning data without population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean, mongoose-populate

I know that this question was asked many many times but i still can't find a solution

So this is my db

**Product :**
[image]

**Ingredient :**

[image]

**Schemas :** 
ingredient.js

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var IngredientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  quantity: {
    value: Number,
    unit: String
  },
  comment: String,
  product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("IngredientSchema", IngredientSchema);
```

**product.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
    trim: true,
    required: "Name cannot be blank"
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
    trim: true
  },
  convertion: [
    {
      unit_from: String,
      unit_to: String,
      value_from: Number,
      value_to: Number
    }
  ],
  default_unit: String
});

const Product = (module.exports = mongoose.model(
  "ProductSchema",
  ProductSchema
));
```

this is the populate function : 
ingredientRoutes.route("/:id").get(function(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id;

```
  Ingredient.findById(id)
    .populate("produit")
    .exec()
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.product, "***");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

this is the result that i'm getting : 
just the id of the product without making the population

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think a lot, but  ".populate("produit")"
produit??

Comment: i've tried .populate("produit") and .populate("Product") & .populate({path :"produit"}) & .populate({path :"Product"}) and i'm getting the same result eachtime